# Bump API Android crash

Tags: java, android, crash, bump

I have a huge problem with the bump API on Android. I setup everything like in the example, the first time I start my activity containing the bump code it works great, now if I go back and start it again it just crash due to a Fatal signal error... It happen right after I call the configure of the bump API.

May I need to not call it again ? But there is nothing to check if it already configured or not.

```
public class BumpActivity extends Activity {
    private IBumpAPI api;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bump);
        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(BumpActivity.this, "Preparing bump", "Loading");
        bindService(new Intent(IBumpAPI.class.getName()), connection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.CHANNEL_CONFIRMED);
        filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.DATA_RECEIVED);
        filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.NOT_MATCHED);
        filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.MATCHED);
        filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.CONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, resultIntent);
        super.onBackPressed(); 
    }
    private final ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {

            Log.i("BumpTest", "onServiceConnected");
            api = IBumpAPI.Stub.asInterface(binder);
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        api.configure("9b17d663752843a1bfa4cc72d309339e",
                                "Bump User");
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        Log.w("BumpTest", e);
                    }

                }
            }.start();
            Log.d("Bump Test", "Service connected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Log.d("Bump Test", "Service disconnected");
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            try {
                if (action.equals(BumpAPIIntents.DATA_RECEIVED)) {
                    getUserDetailFromBump(new String(
                            intent.getByteArrayExtra("data")));
                } else if (action.equals(BumpAPIIntents.MATCHED)) {
                    long channelID = intent
                            .getLongExtra("proposedChannelID", 0);
                    Log.i("Bump Test",
                            "Matched with: "
                                    + api.userIDForChannelID(channelID));
                    api.confirm(channelID, true);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Matched with: "
                                    + api.userIDForChannelID(channelID),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                } else if (action.equals(BumpAPIIntents.CHANNEL_CONFIRMED)) {
                    long channelID = intent.getLongExtra("channelID", 0);
                    api.send(channelID, CurrentUserManager.getSharedManager()
                            .getCurrentUser().getUserId().toString().getBytes());
                } else if (action.equals(BumpAPIIntents.NOT_MATCHED)) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                } else if (action.equals(BumpAPIIntents.CONNECTED)) {
                    mDialog.dismiss(); 
                    api.enableBumping();
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    public void getUserDetailFromBump(String data) {
        Log.i("User Id", data); 
        LoginRequest login = new LoginRequest(getApplicationContext());
        Log.i("Token", login.getArchivedToken()); 
        AsyncHttpClient restRequest = new AsyncHttpClient();
        PersistentCookieStore cookie = new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext()); 
        restRequest.setCookieStore(cookie); 
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("auth_token", login.getArchivedToken()); 
        params.put("user_id", data); 
        Log.i("Request", "Preparing"); 
        restRequest.get(Constantes.API_URL + "users/show.json", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                Log.i("Reponse", response); 
                try {
                    User user = new User(new JSONObject(response));
                    Log.i("User", user.toString()); 
                    //Driver
                    if (CurrentUserManager.getSharedManager().getCurrentUser().getType() == 1){
                        CurrentRouteManager.getSharedManager().getCurrentRoute().addPassanger(user); 
                        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(BumpActivity.this, DriverActivity.class);
                        resultIntent.putExtra("PASSENGER_ADDED", true); 
                        setResult(1, resultIntent);
                        finish(); 
                    }
                    else{
                        Intent p = new Intent(BumpActivity.this, RoutePassenger.class); 
                        p.putExtra("driver", user); 
                        startActivity(p); 
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                Log.i("Error", e.toString()); 
            }

        }); 

    }

    public void onStart() {
        Log.i("BumpTest", "onStart");
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onRestart() {
        Log.i("BumpTest", "onRestart");
        super.onRestart();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        Log.i("BumpTest", "onResume");

        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        Log.i("BumpTest", "onPause");
        try {
            api.disableBumping();

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        Log.i("BumpTest", "onStop");
        try {
            api.disableBumping();

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("BumpTest", "onDestroy");
        try {
            api.disableBumping();

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        unbindService(connection);
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Dimillian77 hii i am making this type of app.get the api demo from github but cant able to connect this one.so can you please give your demo for bump api so i can start this.i want to implement same functionality like you.please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally resolved it few days ago. As I'm not a JAVA expert I think the bug is located within the Bump library. 
If you do api.configure when it is already configured it simply crash. So I ended up making a singleton, ensuring that it is called only once

Here is the code

```
public class BumpConnection {

    protected Context context; 
    private IBumpAPI api;
    private static BumpConnection sharedManager;
    public static synchronized BumpConnection getSharedManager(Context context) {
        if (sharedManager == null) {
            sharedManager = new BumpConnection(context);
        }
        return sharedManager;
    }

    private BumpConnection(Context context){
        this.context = context; 
        context.bindService(new Intent(IBumpAPI.class.getName()), connection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }



    public IBumpAPI getApi() {
        return api;
    }

    public void setApi(IBumpAPI api) {
        this.api = api;
    }



    private final ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {

            Log.i("BumpTest", "onServiceConnected");
            api = IBumpAPI.Stub.asInterface(binder);
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        api.configure("9b17d663752843a1bfa4cc72d309339e",
                                "Bump User");
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        Log.w("BumpTest", e);
                    }

                }
            }.start();
            Log.d("Bump Test", "Service connected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Log.d("Bump Test", "Service disconnected");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I used your solution and it is still not working for me. Whenever I drop the WiFi connection, the FATAL SIGNAL will either appear and in other cases when the BUMPED event is triggered the MATCHED event will never again trigger till I have the app killed and re-launched.

Answer (score -1):

Use Latest bump api , available at git hub, read the README.md file carefully.
There is clearly mentioned that by using .aidl file (that is available in src folder) first compile it by using command

android update project -t android-15 -l path_to/bump-api-library -p path_to_your_project/

in your terminal..
If you are a Linux user then set path up to platform-tools then use this command with ./adb .

Then refresh the project , set this Library project as library in your test bump project..
Also replace your bumpapi key that you received via email